# Simulator display as black screen

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion

I am using mac 10.7.3 lion and installed Xcode 4.3.2 . I have created my first project in Xcode tried to run it on the simulator which  displaying as black screen for a very long time. On top of the Xcode a progress bar displays that it is attaching app to the simulator.

Please help me to debug this problem.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it does take the simulator a long time to launch your app from Xcode. I suggest that you just quit the simulator and Xcode and try again.

Comment: problem remains as same.what might be the reason for this problem?.

Comment: Try this: Quit the simulator. Make a completely new project using the Single View Application Template. Make no changes at all - just run the project. Does it launch? If so, the problem is with your other project. But if not, you can't launch *any* projects on the simulator so you have a bad installation, and should probably delete Xcode and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Quit the simulator and run the project again.